# Autodesk Forge 403 When Trying to Retrieve Issues

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm following the Issue Retrieval tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/retrieve-issues/

After getting a token I'm able to retrieve my hubs, then my projects, but when it comes time to retrieve issues in a project I am getting a 403 forbidden.

Trying to retrieve issues with the following URL:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/[issue_container_id]/issues
```

where `[issue_container_id]` is retrieved from `data[0].relationships.issues.data.id` from the `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/[hub_id]/projects` response

My auth token scope is `data:read` and I've even tried with `data:read` and `data:write` since I was initially trying to write an issue, but also got a 403.

My Forge app has access to BIM 360 API, Data Management API, and WebHook API.
My BIM 360 integration gives the Forge app acess to BIM 360 Account Admin and Document management.

Comment: What's your token type, two-legged token or three-legged? If you're using the three-legged token or two-legged token with user impersonation, the user must have permissions to access Document Management or Field Management.

Comment: Now it supports pure two-legged token to access BIM360 Issues, you can call APIs without giving the user impersonation (i.e. x-user-id)

Comment: @EasonKang Using a two-legged token without user impersonation

Comment: May I ask you a favor to test issue APIs with three-legged token and two-legged token(x-user-id) to check if it doesn’t work either? @AngelSay

Comment: @EasonKang works with three-legged but not two-legged (with or without user impersonation)

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team, will get back A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our engineering team, BIM360 Issue APIs support `three-legged` token only currently. Apologizing for the confusion, the tutorial will be updated soon.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I only tried two legged because the tutorial suggested you could do either.